# Pass argument multiple times in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, arguments, multiple-instances

Is there a way to pass an argument multiple times to different arrays?

What I want to do is:

> r = '1:10:end';       % This doesn't work for me
>   plot(x1(r), y1(r));
>   plot(x2(r), y2(r));
>   ...

and pass `r` to different arrays (with different lengths) in many plot functions. I tried with `[r]` but no success.

Comment: Is `r` supposed to be a string?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just need a way to pass that argument to multiple array functions. If there's a better way, it would be great

Comment: if r is some vector with indices to use, e.g. `r = 1:1:5` you can definitely use it to plot values on positions 1 through 5 from `x1`, `y1` etc

Comment: Mm maybe I didn't specify well, but the arrays have different lengths

Comment: You mean `x1`, `y1` etc?

Comment: x1, y1 must have the same length. But x2, y2 could be different

Comment: Remove quotation marks: `r = 1:10:N;` - but you need to know `N`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that the arrays change in length, so `N` changes too. What I wanted is to avoid writing `1:10:N` for each array.

Comment: Then you need MrAzzaman's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to plot every 10th element of possibly different sized arrays. There are a few ways you could do this. One way would be to write a short function to filter your arrays for you, for instance:

```
plot_10 = @(x,y) plot(x(1:10:end),y(1:10:end));
plot_10(x1,y1);
plot_10(x2,y2);
...
```

EDIT: Just an additional thought. If you wanted to enable the extended functionality of plot (e.g. passing line/colour arguments, etc). You could do something like this:

```
plot_10 = @(x,y,varargin) plot(x(1:10:end),y(1:10:end),varargin{:});
plot_10(x1,t1,'k+');
```

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer solved most of my problems. Is it too difficult if I want more than one plot in the same figure, like `plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)`

Comment: That would make it rather more difficult, I think, as you would have to account for the possibility of statements like `plot(x1, y1,'r+', x2, y2, 'k.');` and the like. Not saying it's impossible, but you'd have to write a separate function file to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To use the "end" operator, it needs to be inside an array access call;

```
n = 10;
r = 1 : 1 : n;
r(1:end) % is legal
r(1:floor(end/2)) % is legal
```

So you could do something like this:

```
s = rand(1,2*n);
s(r)

% to compare...
s( 1:1:n )
```